# Trouble rendering data in React

Tags: reactjs, render, jsx, victory-charts

I am attempting to feed data into a pie graph from `VictoryChart`. Implementing a graph is quite easy. To implement a [pie graph](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-pie/), all you have to do is the following...

```
<VictoryPie
  data={[
    { x: "Cats", y: 35 },
    { x: "Dogs", y: 40 },
    { x: "Birds", y: 55 }
  ]}
/>
```

Notice the `data` format, it is an array of associative arrays of some sort `[{...},{...}]`

Now, in my state, I have something called `pie_data` and `pie_keys`. Essentially, `pie_data` is just an object...

```
{
  "Fac of Engineering & Appl Sci": 8.557902403495994,
  "Faculty of Arts and Science": 53.775188152464196,
  "Faculty of Education": 13.085700412721534,
  "Faculty of Health Sciences": 7.75673707210488,
  "Faculty of Law": 8.07234765719835,
  "Not Faculty Specific": 0.30347171643602816,
  "School of Business": 5.8994901675163876,
  "School of Graduate Studies": 2.537023549405195,
  "School of Religion": 0.012138868657441126
}
```

and `pie_keys` are just lookup values...

```
 ["Fac of Engineering & Appl Sci", "Faculty of Arts and Science", etc.]
```

`pie_keys` are just used to lookup values in `pie_data`. So, essentially, if I want to create a pie graph, I would begin to implement the following...

```
<VictoryPie
  data={[
    { x: "Fac of Engineering & Appl Sci", y: 8.557902403495994 },
    { x: "Faculty of Arts and Science", y: 53.775188152464196 },
    { x: "Faculty of Education", y: 13.085700412721534 },
    ...
    ...
  ]}
/>
```

But I cannot just do it manually. I need to extract them from the state values. So I tried the following...

```
render() {
    const data_distribution = [this.state.pie_keys.map((d) => {x:d, y:this.state.pie_data[d]})];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <VictoryPie
          data = {data_distribution}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The map functions work as intended, I have tested them, `x` is the key value and `y` is the value associated with that key. However, my issue is returning the `data_distribution` in the expected format of `[{x:.., y:...}, {x:..., y:...}, etc.]`. When I try my example above I get an error message...

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; 
(57:69) 55 | 56 | render() { > 57 | const data_distribution = [this.state.pie_keys.map((d) => {x:d, y:this.state.pie_data[d]})]; 
                                                                                                   | ^
```

How do I feed the right format into the pie graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
const data_distribution = [this.state.pie_keys.map((d) => {x:d, y:this.state.pie_data[d]})];
```

With

```
const data_distribution = this.state.pie_keys.map((d) => ({x:d, y:this.state.pie_data[d]}));
```

There are two issues first Array.map itself returns an **Array**. So no need to wrap **data_distribution** in [].

Second problem is around line

```
(d) => {x:d, y:this.state.pie_data[d]}
```

Here the function is trying to return an Object Literal from Arrow Function. This will always return undefined. As the parser doesn't interpret the two braces as an object literal, but as a block statement.The parentheses forces it to parse as Object Literal. Hope this helps